# Programming language suggestion for web development

Tags: web, debian, freepbx

I am trying to make a web application but since I am a beginner in programming I don't know how to achieve this.

I got a web page (freepbx ucp call history) where users see call details(see screenshot).

What I want to do is linking numbers to names on mouse over.
So that a tooltip will appear showing the name linked to that number.

How can I achieve this?What programming language should I use?
Server is debian wheezy

[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENmX.png)

Comment: Programming language suggestions are offtopic as they're completely opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many ways to achieve this.. I would use the framework bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/ ) and if necessary combine it with some jQuery but there are other ways...

Comment: frontend is made using bootstrap.